# Character encoding when passing value to PHP in GET URL parameter

Tags: php

I have the following HTTP GET parameter in my URL what I'm trying to return in a query:

```
Tablets & Phones
```

When I do `var_dump($_GET['my_get_param'])`, the string is not full, instead I'm getting `"Tablets "` (note the space afterwards.) How can I encode the string to get the desired value? I have been trying urlencode and html_specialchars, but without any result.

`var_dump(urlencode($_GET["my_get_param"))` is returning `"Tablets+"`.

Comment: [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/function.urlencode.php)

Comment: That was the first Ans ..thumbs up..

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know, `&` in the URL separates parameters. If you want to include a parameter that contains a `&` character, you need to [**`urlencode`**](http://php.net/urlencode) it.

Answer (score 0):

`&` has a special meaning in HTTP requests and URLs, use `urlencode()` to make sure what you have is what would be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The GET variables must be encoded, because you cannot have spaces in your URL.
For example the space character (" ") converts to %20 when encoded, an Ampersand ("&") converts to %26.

You might want to use [urlencode](http://pt2.php.net/urlencode)